# JMeter: Is it possible to run parallel thread groups on various slave nodes using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have 3 thread groups in my test plan and I have 3 slave nodes (remote servers). I would like to run all these thread groups in parallel but each one on a specific slave node.

```
+ Test Plan 
   + Thread Group X - (192.169.0.1)
       - HTTP Request Defaults
       - Cookie Manager
       + HTTP Request-1
   + Thread Group Y - (192.169.0.2)
       - HTTP Request Defaults
       - Cookie Manager
       + HTTP Request-2
   + Thread Group Z - (192.169.0.3)
       - HTTP Request Defaults
       - Cookie Manager
       + HTTP Request-3
```

Example:

`Thread Group X` on `192.169.0.1`

`Thread Group Y` on `192.169.0.2`

`Thread Group Z` on `192.169.0.3`

Anyone has any idea if something like this is possible on JMeter or not? Any suggestion or thoughts would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options, both assume evaluating [__machineIP() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP)

1. On Thread Group level you can check the host JMeter is running at and set the number of threads or loops correspondingly:

   ```
   ${__jexl3(if ("${__machineIP()}" == "192.169.0.1") {return 0},)}
   ```

   if the above [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) will be executed at `192.169.0.1` host - it will return `0` and JMeter ignores Thread Groups which have 0 threads or loops, this way you can "disable" this or that Thread Group
2. Use [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) (for example applicable to HTTP Requests), the similar [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) triggers request execution on the 192.168.0.1

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You could define user count (Number of Threads) for each thread in user.properties file.

For example, add the following to the `{JMETER_HOME}/bin/user.properties` on salve `192.169.0.2` to run the `Thread Group Y`

```
number.of.threads.threadx=0
number.of.threads.thready=100
number.of.threads.threadz=0
```

Configure other saves with the required number of threads in `{JMETER_HOME}/bin/user.properties`.

Read the Number of threads (JMeter properties) using functions.
Add the following to the Thread groups

[image]

This solution will ensure threads will be created only for the required thread group(s)